# Tracking listbox widget information

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI using tkinter for selecting text files with the end result being the file name along with the path for use with another program. The text files may not be in the same folder.
The GUI is currently capable of:

1. Moving between folders
2. Displaying folders and all text files in the current folder, in separate boxes
3. Selecting files and displaying the selected file names in a separate box

I am carrying a separate StringVar for the path and file name which matches the indices of the listbox widget displaying the selected file names, or trying to at least. I have not found a way to simply add or delete a 'line' to the StringVar as you would a list or array. So I have tried 'extracting' the files (by converting the string back to a list) in order to rewrite them to the same StringVar using the .set this has not gone so well. Major issues being that each time I rewrite the list I am doubling the number of '\'.

If someone knows of an easier/better way of achieving what, I hope, I am describing I would greatly appreciate the input, or directing to additional resources. The code is attached if you want to play with it. Also I am new to python and tkinter so if you see anything that could be done 'better' I'd like to hear that too. Thanks for any input.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import data_Modules as dM
import os

################################################################################
# Change to a nested folder
################################################################################
def update(*arg):
    print(entry1.get())
    folders.set(value =
                tuple([element for element
                       in os.listdir(entry1.get())
                       if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(entry1.get(), element))]))
    dirFiles = [os.path.join(entry1.get(), element) for element
                in os.listdir(entry1.get())
                if element.split('.')[-1] == 'txt']
    dirFiles.sort()
    listFiles.set(value =
                  tuple([line.split('\\')[-1] for line in dirFiles]))

################################################################################
# Return to prior folder
################################################################################    
def uplevel(*arg):
    priorPath = hardDrive
    for line in entry1.get().split('\\')[1:-1]:
        priorPath = os.path.join(priorPath, line)
    parentDir.set(priorPath)
    update()

################################################################################
# Add file to 'memory'
################################################################################
def select(*arg):
    dirFiles = [os.path.join(entry1.get(), element) for element
                in os.listdir(entry1.get())
                if element.split('.')[-1] == 'txt']
    dirFiles.sort()
    print('dirFiles')
    print(dirFiles[int(boxlist2.curselection()[0])])
    print(dirFiles[0])
    temp = retVar(filePath)
    print('temp In')
    for line in temp:
        print(line)
    if all([element != dirFiles[int(boxlist2.curselection()[0])]
           for element in temp]):
        temp.append(dirFiles[int(boxlist2.curselection()[0])])
        temp.sort()
        print('temp Out')
        for line in temp:
            print(line)
        filePath.set(value = tuple(temp))    
    selFiles.set(value = tuple([line.split('\\')[-1] for line in temp]))

################################################################################
# Remove file from 'memory'
################################################################################
def deselect(*arg):
    temp = retVar(filePath)
    temp.sort()
    del temp[int(boxlist3.curselection()[0])]
    filePath.set(value = tuple(temp))
    selFiles.set(value = tuple([line.split('\\')[-1] for line in temp]))

################################################################################
# Attempt at retrieving data
################################################################################
def retVar(strVar):
    if strVar.get() == '':
        print('\n')
        return []
    else:
        if strVar.get()[-2:] == ',)':
            print([strVar.get()[2:-3]])
            return [strVar.get()[2:-3]]
        else:
            print(strVar.get()[3:-3].split('\', \''))
            return strVar.get()[3:-3].split('\', \'')

# Create window and Change name of window
root = Tk()
root.title('Main Window')
# Main hard drive for the computer
hardDrive = 'C:\\'
# Create necessary variables
parentDir = StringVar()
folders = StringVar()
listFiles = StringVar()
selFiles = StringVar()
filePath = StringVar()
parentDir.set(value = hardDrive)
dirFiles = []

# Generate all the widgets
entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable = parentDir)
entry1.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = 'WE')
entry1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
entry1.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

label1 = ttk.Label(root, text = 'Current Directory')
label1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'WE')
label1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
label1.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

#Not currently used
#label2 = ttk.Label(root, text = 'Parent')
#label2.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = 'WE')
#label2.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
#label2.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

label3 = ttk.Label(root, textvariable = parentDir.get())
label3.grid(column = 3, row = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = 'WE')
label3.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
label3.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

label4 = ttk.Label(root, text = 'Folders')
label4.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = 'WE')
label4.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
label4.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

label5 = ttk.Label(root, text = 'Files')
label5.grid(column = 3, row = 2, sticky = 'WE')
label5.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
label5.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

label6 = ttk.Label(root, text = 'Files')
label6.grid(column = 5, row = 2, sticky = 'WE')
label6.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
label6.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

button1 = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Go', command = update)
button1.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = 'W')
button1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
button1. rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

button2 = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Back', command = uplevel)
button2.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
button2.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
button2. rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

button3 = ttk.Button(root, text = 'deselect', command = deselect)
button3.grid(column = 5, row = 6)
button3.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
button3. rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

button4 = ttk.Button(root, text = 'select', command = select)
button4.grid(column = 5, row = 4)
button4.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
button4. rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

update()

boxlist1 = Listbox(root, listvariable = folders, height = 10,
                   font = 18, width = 40, selectmode = 'single')
boxlist1.grid(column = 0, row = 3, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 5)
boxlist1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
boxlist1.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

boxlist2 = Listbox(root, listvariable = listFiles, height = 10,
                   font = 18, width = 40, selectmode = 'single')
boxlist2.grid(column = 3, row = 3, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 5)
boxlist2.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
boxlist2.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)


boxlist3 = Listbox(root, listvariable = selFiles, height = 10,
                   font = 18, width = 40, selectmode = 'single')
boxlist3.grid(column = 6, row = 3, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 5)
boxlist3.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
boxlist3.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)



boxlist1.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda e: print(boxlist1.get(int(boxlist1.curselection()[0]))))
boxlist1.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda e: parentDir.set(os.path.join(entry1.get(), boxlist1.get(int(boxlist1.curselection()[0])))))
boxlist1.bind('<Double-ButtonRelease-1>', update)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep my values in an iterable/sequence and draw the listbow widget by calling the following function:

```
def redraw_listbox(w, seq):
    w.delete(0, "end")
    for i, elem in enumerate(seq):
        w.insert(i, str(elem))
```